# Increase ISO or use Photoshop post production exposure correction ?

Tags: post-processing, iso

With some slow lens, and in some situation I tend to under expose. Situation like action where i need to freeze movement, I use obviously fast shutter.

When I open my RAW in Photoshop and I click the magic "Auto" correction, Photoshop increase exposure, 1 or 2 stop.

Then I notice "noise" .

My question is: is it better to increase on camera ISO, or post production action ? Or it is simply THE SAME ?

If I increase ISO i increase noise.

If I increase exposure in post production i increase noise....

Thanks

Comment: Try it. -- Fred Picker.

Comment: To a very great degree, it depends on the camera and how it is designed. The answers to the suggested duplicate are beginning to get a bit long in the tooth.